# Right drawer marginTop not being set

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a base activity with an layout defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="end">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_base"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_base"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_base_drawer"/>

    <FrameLayout

        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The `include` part is where I set my `toolbar` and have a container that will receive a `fragment`.

Has you can see by the `id`, the `FrameLayout` will act as an `right drawer`.
I want that this `drawer` is placed bellow the `toolbar`.
I've tried to add an `android:layout_marginTop` to the drawer but  with no success (that `200dp` value is only for tests and the final value will be `56dp`). When I open the drawer it takes all the screen height (bellow status bar).

Here is an image:
[image]

How can I put the `frame layout` bellow the `toolbar`?

Comment: its not work that way using margintop; you have to use this in your fragment layout or if you want to show action bar then change your main activity layout

Answer (score 0):

Use a linear layout with a vertical orientation and place the toolbar and frame layout inside. Use "wrap_content" in the height property of the frame layout so that it will not take full height of its parent..

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_base"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

       <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem with that approach is that it gives me `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams` because this line in code `mNavigationDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, findViewById(R.id.right_drawer));`